# LOAD CSV from url

Tags: neo4j, proxy, cypher, load-csv

I am using the LOAD CSV statement to access a csv file from a public url. It works fine whenever I am not behind the proxy of my company. As soon as the proxy is active, the file can no longer be accessed with the statement.

The error message is `Couldn't load the external resource at: <MY_PUBLIC_URL>`.

I've set the usual environment variables (`HTTP_PROXY`, `HTTPS_PROXY`) and I can access the file e.g. with bash or from python urllib, using node.js or from the browser address bar.

I also added `dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls=true` to the Neo4j conf file, as well as `dbms.jvm.additional=-Dhttps.proxyHost=<MY_PROXY>` and `dbms.jvm.additional=-Dhttps.proxyPort=<MY_PROXY>` as suggested in other threads.

I've tried it from a plain Neo4j installation, as well as from the Neo4j Docker container, in both scenarios I get the same error when behind the proxy.

Can LOAD CSV get behind the proxy and if so, how?